# Rails use column from different activerecord model as foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys

```
class Model1
 #has an column "attr1"
end

class Model2
 #has an column "attr2"
end

class Model3
 #has an column "attr3"
 belongs_to :model2

 belongs_to my_model_1, class_name: 'Model1', primary_key: :attr1, foreign_key: "#{model2.attr2}-#{attr3}"
end
```

I get the following error doing this:

```
  `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `model2' for Model1 (call 'Model1.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NameError)
```

Is there a way of using a column from belongs_to relation as part of the foreign_key the way I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a dynamic value to `:foreign_key` so you will have to write it manually using the value you've chosen for the column name:

```
belongs_to my_model_1, class_name: 'Model1', primary_key: :attr1,
                       foreign_key: "model2_attr2_attr3"
```

You can check out the docs [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to).